# how to get value of promise and use it in selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to pick media devices for video call app. I want to create selector, which contain 3 selector, one for mic, 2nd for video and 3rd for speaker (each in its own selection). I try to do this in this way, but smth is wrong, because selector is empty and if I console the result of deviceType, console output Promise{}
if you know other way to do this pls write;

```
import Select from 'react-select';
import './SettingButton.css';
import videoon from './videoon.png';
import micon from './micon.png';
import speaker from './speaker.png';


let deviceDetected = (navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() 
.then((devices) => {
   return (devices.map((device) => 
    (device.kind + ": " + device.label)));
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
}));


 const deviceType = async()=> {
   const a = await deviceDetected;
   console.log (a)
 }


export default function SettingButton(props) {
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } 
  
    return  (props.onClickDisplay ? (
      <div className="settingButton">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
  
        <div className="iconStyle">
          <img src = {micon} alt='microphone' height='30px' width ='30px' className='imgStyle'/>
         <div className="textStyle">
         <Select option={deviceType()}/>
         </div>
         </div>
  
         <div className="iconStyle">
        <img src = {videoon} alt='video' height='30px' width ='30px' className='imgStyle'/>
          <div className="textStyle">
          <Select option={deviceType()}/>
          </div>
          </div>
          
         <div className="iconStyle">
         <img src = {speaker} alt='speaker' height='30px' width ='30px' className='imgStyle'/>
         <div className="textStyle">
         <Select option={deviceType()}/>
         </div>
         </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    ) : null)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

await wait for a promise...
try this to make a promise

```js
let deviceDetected = ()=>{
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() 
.then((devices) => {
   let res = (devices.map((device) => 
    (device.kind + ": " + device.label)));
    resolve(res)
})
.catch(function(err) {
  reject(err)
  console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
}));
})
}
```

Comment: not working, my problem is <Select option={deviceType()}/>

Comment: in your code,` const a = await deviceDetected; ` , a will be undefined